# LTI Parameters in D2L

Tags: html, desire2learn, lti

I am trying a new version of D2L and seeing two values that are missing from the LTI links. The values are context_id and ext_d2l_username both of these exist previously, is there any setting we need to do to make these values flow with the rest of the html post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable sending context_id and ext_d2l_username, you first have to configure tool consumer information to allow sending them, and then make sure you also enabled it for that LTI link.

To configure tool consumer information:

- Using an account with necessary privileges, from the Admin Tools choose External Learning Tools.
- Click on the Settings link located close to the top right corner of the page.
- Enable "Allow sending context information to tool provider" for context_id, and "Allow sending system username to tool provider" for ext_d2l_username.

After that, choose your LTI Link and under its configuration do the following:

- Enable "Send context information to tool provider" for context_id.  Note: this option will only be available if "Allow sending context information to tool provider" has been enabled in the Configure Tool Consumer Information screen.
- Enable "Send system username too tool provider" for ext_d2l_username.  Note: this option will only be available if "Allow sending system username to tool provider" has been enabled in the Configure Tool Consumer Information screen.

In order for the context_id to be sent when LTI link is launched, the link has to be launched from a course context.  It will be be sent if it was added from a top org level.